# "Could not find User without ID" ActiveRecord Error and editing trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I am having some trouble with my rails app and I think I went a little out of my own depth. I am creating a simple alumni application and I want users to be able to join organizations. For some reason in my new join page I get the error "Couldn't find User without an ID". I want to know why the ID isn't passing in, which would imply signed_in? = false. I don't know why everything worked find when I created other additions to my users controller but here it refuses to take on the logged in user id. I feel like I am missing something simple, let me know if updates are necessary!

Here is the relevant information in my Users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update, :index, :show, :join]
before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update, :join]
before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

def join
end

def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @organization = @user.organization
end

def create
   @user = User.new(user_params)
   if @user.save
       sign_in @user
       flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
       redirect_to @user
  else
      render 'new'
  end
end
...
      private

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name,:email, :password, :password_confirmation,:organization_id)
end


def signed_in_user
  unless signed_in?
    store_location
    redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
  end
end

def correct_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
end

def admin_user
  redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
end
end
```

I included the def create method because I tried editing it to redirect users to the join page right after login but then I came across this error and I thought that was the problem so i switched it back. I guess it wasnt.... NOTE: I am basing a lot of this app off of the Hartl tutorial if that is helpful.

Comment: What does your routes file look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a Memberships controller and model with a belongs_to :user (has_many :memberships for User & Organization), instead of defining a join method in the Users controller. The controller should be responsible for adding/deleting organization user-memberships. From that controller you fetch the user info by @user = User.find(:id) and don't forget to properly set the route file for nested resources.

```
resources :users do
    resources :memberships
end
```

Also note that your join method doesn't create any instance variables for the view (@user). It looks like it properly goes through the signed_in_user action but nothing is instantiated in the join method.

Comment: thanks! that is totally the way to go, I feel like a moron haha, should have realized that

Answer (score 0):

Change line 3 to:

```
before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
```

If the purpose of "join" is to create a user, then there should not be a user yet. However if your purpose for "join" is to get the current user you should add this to your join method:

```
@user = current_user
```

Answer (score -3):

What about if you changed it to this:

```
def show
@users = User.all
@user = @users.find(params[:id])
@organization = @user.organization
end
```